# Binding a Property Data Table @ JSF with a Managed Bean

Tags: java, jsf

I have a JSF page that has a property datatable a.k.a

> p:dataTable

I need to bind this dataTable to a backing bean, question is:
How do I instantiate the variable that will bind the property data table on my backing bean?
Clearly HTTPDataTable does not work

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean h:dataTable. p:dataTable is the PrimeFaces component, as far as I know.

```
<h:dataTable rows="somenumber" value="#{BackingBeanName.BackingBeanList}" var="var_name">
   <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Column Header" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="var_name.property_name" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
       ...
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

PrimeFaces has some nice examples of how to code their dataTable component, its very similar.

Comment: Nope, actually I was meaning a p:DataTable, is there a way to bind this component to a variable on my backing bean? Thanks for the help though

Comment: Well, if you're using PrimeFaces, then yes there is.  Its done basically the same as with the standard JSF dataTable.  If you're not using PrimeFaces, maybe you could elaborate on the library you are using, or be a little more specific in your question.

Comment: Yep I am using PrimeFaces, by standard JSF datatable you mean the HTTP Data Table?  Thanks

Comment: Found the solution, I feel so dumb. variable is a DataTable with the import org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable;

Comment: You can find a lot of answers to PrimeFaces questions on Stackoverflow, but PrimeFaces also has a forum I find helpful. Goto their homepage and click on support, the user forum is the first listing. Also, a free older version of the users guide (newer version on sale soon).